# java: writing an image file with ImageIO

Tags: java, file, javax.imageio

My code looks as so:

```
    File saveLocation = new File("src\\database\\images\\");
    ImageIO.write(this.image, "jpg", saveLocation);
```

And my error is this:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\database\images (Access is denied)

images is a folder in my netbeans project
I can read from it just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Two things

1. `src\\database\\images\\` is likely a directory, you need to supply a file name for the image, something like `src\\database\\images\\Output.jpg` for example
2. You shouldn't be referencing the `src` directory, ever.  Instead, you need to save the file somewhere the file system.  You could use `./Output.jpg` for the current working directory (which is typically the project directory)

Answer (score 2):

Ummm. That's a directory... how could you read from it just fine? All I notice is that you are missing a file name.

```
 File saveLocation = new File("src/database/images/myImage.jpg"); // <-- Use `/`.
```